# How can I fix a "No site configured at this address" error?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, browser-cache

My internet connection is working fine, but when I go to http://www.google.com/ in Internet Explorer I get the following error:

```
No site configured at this address
```

Cutting and pasting the exact address into another browser gets to the site just fine. How can I get this working again in IE?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: @daxlerod No proxy. It ended up being a cache problem on the user's system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using IE's Developer Tools, delete the cache for the specific domain like so:

1. Open Internet Explorer 10
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or click the settings gear icon in the upper-right corner and click "F12 developer tools")
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or in the menu bar that appears on the lower
   portion of the screen, click Cache -> "Clear browser cache for this domain...")
4. Click Yes
5. Try going to the site again and you should be all set

Please note that before figuring this out, I had deleted the entire cache on the user's system, in which the google.com cache should be included. Deleting the entire cache did NOT fix the problem though, but deleting it for the specific domain did.

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd try setting your internet's settings to default, that normally fixes these kind of problems.

If that doesn't work, try installing Firefox or Chrome then uninstalling IE then using Chrome or Firefox re-install IE.

If that doesn't work it might be as simple as clearing the browser cache or deleting cookies/history.

Alternatively try opening the page as cached or InPrivate.

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings ->Internet Options -> Advanced (TAB) -> Reset...(button) 
And Settings ->Internet Options -> Advanced (TAB) -> Restore advanced settings

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue.

Click `Tools` and click `Delete Browsing History`.
Then it should open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. The only change that occurred was that Microsoft had upgraded Windows Internet Explorer to version 10. My internet banking website was also affected. I tried clearing caches, deleting cookies and explorer history to no avail. In desperation I uninstalled Windows Internet Explorer 10 and now use Internet Explorer 9. Both problems have disappeared and Google is behaving itself. I am now averse to any further versions of the explorer Microsoft might supply unless I am assured that they will contain no problems.